# How to parse json objects not array using jq

Tags: json, stream, jq

For example:

```
echo '{"p":2}{"q":3}' | jq '.'
```

How do I select the first object? I want the object below:

```
{"p":2}
```

Comment: @Inian - It's valid as a JSON stream, which I think it reasonable to assume is the OP's intent.

Comment: @peak: I wasn't sure of OP's expectation. Are they looking to get just `{}`, or it was a just a placeholder to contain some meaningful input inside

Comment: @inian - It makes no difference. `{}` is a valid JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the -n command-line option, e.g.:

```
jq -n input
```

or

```
jq -n 'first(inputs)'
```

Comment: `echo '{"p":2}{"q":3}' | jq -n 'first(inputs)'` works. Thank you.

Comment: If there are five objects and I wanted the 3rd, how would I do it?

Comment: To get the nth object (0-based) : `echo '{"p":2}{"q":3}{"r":4}{"s":5}{"t":6}' | jq -n 'nth(2;inputs)'` -> `{"r":4}`

Comment: `echo '{"p":2}{"q":3}{"r":4}{"s":5}{"t":6}' | jq --slurp '.[2]'` also works!

Comment: Re "*`jq --slurp '.[2]'` also works*", yeah, `jq --slurp '...'` is the same as `jq -n '[ inputs ] | ...'` These aren't as good as using `first` and `nth` as they require loading the entire stream into memory at once.